# How to get the divs current scroll position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, reactjs

I want to know the **scroll position** of a div.
I have two buttons left and right and in between there is a scroll-able div with data populated inside it.
I want to disable the button at the right if there is no data in right and disable the button to the left if no more data at the left.
For that i think i need to know the current scroll position. Any suggestion to enhance this will be awesome.

```
 `    return <div className="row">
        <div ref="previous_column" onClick={this.shift_left} href="#" style={style_div}></div>
        <div className="table-container" ref="table_container"> 
            <div className="sliding-window">
                    {this.props.grocery_cart.delivery_slots.map(function(obj) {
                            return <div key={d}>
                                        <CalendarDetail values={d} ref="delivery_date"/>
                                    </div>
                    }.bind(this))}
             </div>
        </div>
        <div ref="next_column" href="#" onClick={this.shift_right} style={style_div} className="plr-slide"></div>
 </div>`
```

I have just added few relevant codes.

The Previous columns and next columns are the divs (left and right button)

The Table Container is a fixed div and the sliding window inside it slides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using jQuery like so:

```
//axis y position (or top position)
$('[ref="table_container"]').scrollTop()
//axis x position (or left position)
$('[ref="table_container"]').scrollLeft()
```

Or using javascript only like so:

```
//axis y position (or top position)
document.querySelectorAll('[ref="table_container"]').scrollTop;
//axis x position (or left position)
document.querySelectorAll('[ref="table_container"]').scrollLeft;
```

You can read more about it here.

> [**Element.scrollLeft**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft)
>
> The Element.scrollLeft property gets or sets the number of pixels that an element's content is scrolled to the left.

Comment: i want to scroll in horizantal.. Left to right and disable .Does scrollTop() give me the x axis position?

Comment: Thank you so much. 
`$('.table-container').scrollLeft()` 
This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use div.position();

And then do position.top

Comment: I want to the left right position ... scroll top give mes vertical position

Comment: so you need div.position().left

Comment: @Attenzione what he said.

Comment: he wants the scroll position... not the position of the element.. Read the question